# Parseable output from NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to write a small application that wraps some functions inside of NPM from another language.  "npm list" is giving me output with a nice visual tree, but I need something easier to parse.  -parsable is giving me a flat list of modules, but I would like to have some of the metadata available in "npm ll".  Is there a switch or something for NPM that lets me get JSON output?  Right now the only way I can figure to do this is to write a node app that uses the npm module to push json to the standard output.

Comment: Check with Isaacs, but you may be allowed to hit the npm datastore directly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you want to do

```
npm ls --json
```